# load articles with the included tags of the group

Tags: arrays, laravel, undefined

I would like to show in a group all articles which have the same tags as the group. 
For exampel:

The group has as tags: laravel, php, html. Then I would like to let all articles, which have exactly the same tags. So all the articles with the tags laravel, php, html.

Not all articles with the only one same tag, only article with have all the same tags. $tagIdArray are the tags of the group.

I tried this code:

```
 $tagIdArray = [2,3,4];
                $article = Article::with('comments', 'tags')->whereIn('privacy', [1, 2])->where('status', 1)
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($tagIdArray) {
                        return $query->tags->pluck('id')->all() == $tagIdArray;
                    })
                    ->latest()->paginate(15);
```

but I always get the error message:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$tags
```

Post Model

```
  public function tags()
        {
            return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable')->withTimestamps();
        }
```

Tag Model

```
public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Taggable Model

```
public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }
```

EDIT:

For example, if I show all groups and I want to use a random image of the articel as a group image. How do I best implement this?

```
@foreach ($groups as $group)
{{$group->name}}                      
<img src="-----load random picture from articles that is in this group------" alt="" />
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you post Article and Tags Models?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick:

```
$tagIdArray = [2,3,4];
$article = Article::with('comments', 'tags')
  ->whereIn('privacy', [1, 2])
  ->where('status', 1)
  ->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tagIdArray) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $tagIdArray);
  }, '>=', count($tagIdArray))
  ->latest()
  ->paginate(15);
```

**whereHas()** lets you filter only models that have a related model (1st argument) that match constraints defined by callback (2nd argument).

In addition to that, you can say how many related model that match given constraints returned model should have - this is what 2 last arguments do. The code above will return articles that have at least all the tags with IDs in **$tagIdArray** - it will also include articles that have more tags than those 3 provided. If you want to return articles that have all and only the tags provided in **$tagIdArray**, replace **>=** operator with **=**.

Comment: can I use that directly in the blade template?

Comment: Well, if you have a way to run PHP code in the template, you an run any PHP code you like. But why would you put it in the template? It's hard to reuse it this way.The least I would do is creating a static method in Article model an calling that from within the template.

Comment: I have added an example in my question

Comment: I'd add a method in Group model that would returned collection of articles using the code above. Then, simply call random() on this collection to get random article and show it's image.